# Why is this subset associated to a $2$-tensor open and dense?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $S$ be a symmetric $(0, 2)$ tensor on a Riemannian manifold $M$. Define $E_S : M \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $E_S(x) = \left(\text{the number of distinct eigenvalues of } S_x\right)$. I've seen the following claims in several papers:

> - $M_S \doteq \left\{x \in M \ \vert \ E_s \text{ is constant in a neighbourhood of } x \right\}$ is an open dense subset of $M$
> - The eigenvalues of $S$ are distinct and smooth in each connected component $U$ of $M_S$.

I'm a having a hard time proving these facts in a rigorous enough manner. It "feels" true since in some sense the eigenvalues should be smooth, but I can't see how to formalize this precisely (smooth from where to where? how to prove smoothness?). I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Something is fishy. What if you take a (right) cylinder over a round $2$-sphere, all sitting in $\Bbb R^k$, $k\ge 4$? The eigenvalues of the second fundamental form are $0$ (with multiplicity $k-3$ and $1$ (with multiplicity $2$). How is the second bulleted statement to hold?

Comment: A few comments: Eigenvalues only make sense for endomorphisms, not $(0,2)$ tensors, so really one isn’t talking about $S$, but rather an endomorphism defined from $S$ using the metric isomorphism (but ok maybe for brevity people suppress this). Openness is clear by definition, while denseness I’d have to think about. THe second bullet point seems wrong. Just take a fixed linear operator, say the zero operator; this has a unique eigenvalue, namely $0$, so they’re not distinct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Just to clarify, you're talking about $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, right?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I agree. Thanks for the comments, it was a good sanity check. I'm having a hard time showing denseness

Comment: No, $\times\Bbb R^{k-3}$. We need a hypersurface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The function $E_S$ is lower semicontinuous**: In a coordinate chart the characteristic polynomial depends continuously on the coefficients of $S$, and hence the eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity) depend continuously on the coefficients of $S$. Thus if we have $k$ distinct roots at some point $p$, then by ensuring the coefficients of $S$ don't change too much, we can ensure we keep at least $k$ distinct roots near $p$ (but possibly we will get more).

Then density of $M_S$ is a consequence of:

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a topological space and $f: X \to \mathbb{Z}$ a lower semicontinuous function which is bounded above. Then $U = \lbrace x : f \text{ is constant on a neighborhood of } x \rbrace$ is dense in $X$.

*Proof*. Pick a neighborhood $V \subseteq X$; it suffices to find a nonempty open subset $W \subseteq V$ on which $f$ is constant. (For then $W \subseteq U$ by definition, so $U$ intersects every open neighborhood, so is dense.)

Consider for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ the set
$$
  A_m = f^{-1}\big([m, \infty)\big) \cap V.
$$
This is an open subset of $V$ by hypothesis, and when $m$ is large the set $A_m$ is empty (since $f$ is bounded above). Let $N$ be the largest integer such that $A_N$ is nonempty. Then $A_N = f^{-1}(\lbrace N \rbrace) \cap V$, that is, $A_n$ is a nonempty open subset of $V$ on which $f$ is constant.